# Boost Serialization Version Bad

Tags: c++, boost, xml-serialization, boost-serialization

The following code when run with version 1.49.0 of the boost serialization library clobbers the version number.

```
#include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::archive;

class Nested {
public:
    explicit Nested()
    : mC()
    { }

    explicit Nested(char c)
    : mC(c)
    { }

private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int)
    {
        using boost::serialization::make_nvp;
        ar & make_nvp("c", mC);
    };

private:
    char mC;
};

BOOST_CLASS_VERSION(Nested, 0);

int main()
{
    Nested n('c');

    {
        using boost::serialization::make_nvp;
        xml_oarchive ar(cout);
        ar << make_nvp("Nested", n);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output with version 1.49.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<!DOCTYPE boost_serialization>
<boost_serialization signature="serialization::archive" version="9">
<Nested class_id="0" tracking_level="0" version="2057815296">
        <c>99</c>
</Nested>
</boost_serialization>
```

When I run with an older version I get the 0 version as expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<!DOCTYPE boost_serialization>
<boost_serialization signature="serialization::archive" version="6">
<Nested class_id="0" tracking_level="0" version="0">
        <c>99</c>
</Nested>
</boost_serialization>
```

Am I missing something that changed across versions? Anyone else experienced this?

Comment: I would say this is a bug in Boost.Serialization (you can submit a bug report [here](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/)), but there is an easy workaround: add `BOOST_CLASS_VERSION(Nested, 0)` in namespace scope after your `Nested` class definition.

Comment: I actually tried that, if I add `BOOST_CLASS_VERSION(Nested, 0)` immediately after the closing brace of the Nested class, I still have the same problem. I will submit a report. Thanks.

Comment: Just FYI, There were some bugs a couple of versions back with boost serialize that had to do with the datatype that the version # is- if I recall correctly it went from int to unsigned short.